# How can I edit .sol files in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, flash

I want to learn the format of .sol files, so that I can add an entry to

> "C:\Users{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys"

Or is there a way to

1. Open and view SOL files
2. Edit contents of SOL files
3. Create new SOL files.

in .NET?

The requirement is to add a website in Flash player settings of *Add camera and  microphone settings*.

Comment: What are "SOL files"? Do you refer to [this one](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/sol)?

Comment: @UweKeim: sol files are flash cookie files which is used to save websites having flash player settings we visiting. I would need to add a website programmatically into this settings file using .net